# fatal: pathspec '.' did not match any files when trying git rm

Tags: git

I am just running following command on a folder which is part of `git repo`

The command I am running is: `git rm -r --cached .` However git is constantly throwing following error:

`fatal: pathspec '.' did not match any files`

I have no idea why is that. `.` definitely exists and is definitely part of a git repo. The error does not explain much in detail

Comment: To remove any cached files in current folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have gotten yourself into a folder with no tracked files. Since git does not track folders, only files, there is no useful sense in which this folder "exists" for git.

Comment: You are right. It was because cache was empty. But i still feel like the error message did not convey. I agree, I should had known better and realized that I am dealing with cache with `git rm` but git should had been more intuitive with error message here.